# Why does my question need 'details or clarity?'

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen

I asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/769334/359074) question, which is simply about how an outside observer would observe an in falling object into a black hole. The question is simple and clear: Due to the slowing of time as the event horizon nears, would the object eventually appear flattened to an outside observer?

I fail to see how this question is lacking in clarity. What more needs to be clarified?

Comment: Same happened to me with my posts, I don't know how I could make them better. I'm talking about these posts: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766582/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/766590/

Comment: It sounds like a mega duplicate. We are more than 12 years in.

Comment: @PeterMortensen FWIW, I searched for dupes and didn't find any at the time of asking.

Comment: At the least you have not responded to questions in the comments trying to get at just what you are actually asking.

Comment: @JonCuster I answered that question by editing in the 'outside observer' part.

Comment: I have no skin in this but I admit I never quite understand questions of the type “what would this look like?”.  What does this mean “how would something appear”?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero What would the pattern of the photons hitting someone's retina be, as a function of time?